# Open source java libraries for CVS & PVCS repositories

Tags: java, cvs, pvcs

What are good open source java libraries for connecting to CVS & PVCS repositories?

In a way similar to SVNKit for SVN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jcvs](http://www.jcvs.org/)? [javacvs](http://javacvs.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Thanks. These are good to start with. Are there any example code or good documentations for these libraries. I couldn't find anything :( or was I not looking properly. Do you of anything for PVCS? Thanks for the starter though.

Comment: I just googled for "java cvs"... I can't believe you couldn't do this for yourself.

Comment: I have been mostly concentrating on PVCS truly. I did find jcvs but could not find any good tutorial or documentation to start with :(